# Meaningful error messages when using LaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, beamer, tikz-pgf, errors, debugging

When I have TikZ images or I include `.png` graphics, I need to use PDFLaTeX instead of plain `vanilla` LaTeX. (That is, I need to use PDFLaTeX all the time, rather than just when I want to produce the final PDF).

Sometimes I forget that my current document (or one `\include`d in it) contains one of these things. The compilation using latex doesn't work. The errors I get out when this happens don't seem to be meaningful: they don't just say

> No such file `image.eps`

or

> LaTeX can't work TikZ

or the like. Is there anyway I can make these kinds of errors more transparent?

I've often spent ages fiddling with insignificant other bits of code, because I haven't realised it's the image that is messing up the compilation. [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) also sometimes messes up in LaTeX, but I normally spot that one.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just always use `pdflatex`?

Comment: I was led to believe that latex compiles quicker, and it's the default for AucTeX in emacs (I know I could change that, but I'm lazy)

Comment: On modern computers I do not think that the speed difference is really noticeable. I think on most of my documents the only thing that really takes some time is TikZ.

Comment: To put that statement to test, I compiled the paper from http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex-bench/ with `latex` and `pdflatex`. `latex` takes around 0.64s, while `pdflatex` takes around 0.75s. So you are correct, but I do not think the difference really matters. Also the historic comparison is quite interesting: http://ftp.complang.tuwien.ac.at/franz/latex-bench

Comment: For the whole LaTeX source (latex source2e.tex) it's 2.8s vs 3.1s.

Comment: TikZ works fine with regular LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf. At least it does for me.

Comment: Typically latex + dvips + ps2pdf is *much* slower than simply using pdflatex.

Comment: And `xelatex` is the slowest!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `ifpdf` package to test at the beginning of your document whether you're running with pdflatex and, if not, make latex crash with a more meaningful error message.

Comment: Ideally, redefine the appropriate macros to insert blanks (similar to the `draft` option …).

Answer (score 2):

If you have both `includedimage.png` and `includedimage.eps` in the same directory and your LaTeX code doesn't specify the extension, i.e. it says `\includegraphics{includedimage}`, then latex will pick up the .eps file and pdflatex will use the .png.  Even if you don't feel like converting your .png, you could just use a blank placeholder image in .eps format so that latex will also compile correctly.  (If you do feel like converting them but don't currently have an easy way to do it, I recommend [ImageMagick convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) as an excellent free utility.)